# Locking mechanism on Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, locking, atomic

I found a concurrent issue on my application where there are two threads that try to do write operation in same time on same node or relationship in Neo4J v2.2.5.

I managed to reproduce the issue using simple way:

1. Download and import example neo4j movie database: http://example-data.neo4j.org/files/cineasts_12k_movies_50k_actors_2.1.6.zip
   Since the database is old, so you have to add `allow_store_upgrade=true` in `conf/neo4j.properties` to enable auto database upgrade.
2. Start the neo4j and run this query on neo4jshell:

   ```
   match (a:Actor {name: "Claude Jade"}), (m:Movie)
   merge (a)-[:ACTS_IN]->(m);
   ```

   This will create ACTS_IN relationship from the "Claude Jade" Actor to all Movie nodes. The reason of doing this is to make the delete "Claude Jade" Actor node process (see no. 4 below) more longer so the chance of concurrent issue happening is more bigger.
3. Download curl command-line program if you don't have it yet. We will use curl to send query to neo4j.
4. Create a bash script file (filename is up to you) with content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   curl -XPOST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"statements" : [ {"statement" : "MATCH (n:Actor {name: \"Claude Jade\"}) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() DELETE n, r"} ]}' &
   curl -XPOST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"statements" : [ {"statement" : "MATCH (n:Actor {name: \"Claude Jade\"}) CREATE (n)-[:ACTS_IN]->(m:Movie {title: \"Hello World\"}) RETURN m"} ]}' &

   wait
   ```

   This will run two curl process in parallel where the 1st process will try to delete the "Claude Jade" Actor and all of its relationships, and the 2nd process will try to create new ACTS_IN relationship to the "Claude Jade" Actor.
5. Run the script file on bash, e.g. `$ ./test.sh`

Here is the result I got:

```
{
    "results" : [{
            "columns" : ["m"],
            "data" : [{
                    "row" : [{
                            "title" : "Hello World"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "errors" : []
} {
    "results" : [{
            "columns" : [],
            "data" : []
        }
    ],
    "errors" : [{
            "code" : "Neo.DatabaseError.Transaction.CouldNotCommit",
            "message" : "org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: Node record Node[3150,used=false,group=55,prop=-1,labels=Inline(0x0:[]),light] still has relationships",
            "stackTrace" : "java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: Node record Node[3150,used=false,group=55,prop=-1,labels=Inline(0x0:[]),light] still has relationships\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransitionalTxManagementKernelTransaction.commit(TransitionalTxManagementKernelTransaction.java:87)\r\n\tat org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionHandle.closeContextAndCollectErrors(TransactionHandle.java:278)\r\n\tat 
            ...
```

Note: if you don't see any transaction error, then you have to reimport again the movie database and re-run the steps above.

So from what I've seen, the deletion failed because it tried to delete the Actor node and its of all of ACTS_IN relationships, it did the MATCH query first (`MATCH (n:Actor {name: \"Claude Jade\"}) OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()`) but before it executed the `DELETE n, r`, the 2nd process managed to insert the new ACTS_IN relationship to the Actor node so that's why the deletion failed because when it did try to execute the DELETE, the Actor already have one new relationship added.

I wonder if there is locking mechanism on Neo4J that can be used to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You're observing a classic race condition. To prevent that you need to grab a lock on the `Claude` node. Cypher does not have a syntax for explicitly grabbing locks, so we just set a fake property as first action and delete that property in the end - this has the side effect of grabbing a lock. So change your two statements:

```
MATCH (n:Actor {name: "Claude Jade"}) 
SET n._fake = 1   // grabs the lock as first action
WITH n
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-() 
DELETE n, r

MATCH (n:Actor {name: "Claude Jade"}) 
SET n._fake = 1 // grab the lock early
CREATE (n)-[:ACTS_IN]->(m:Movie {title: "Hello World"}) 
REMOVE n._fake   // get rid of fake property
RETURN m
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution, I have tried it, sometimes it works, but sometimes I got error for the 2nd curl process (create new ACTS_IN relationship): `{"results":[],"errors":[{"code":"Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound","message":"Unable to load NODE with id 3150."}]}`

Comment: With usage of the fake property you're effectively serializing the two statements, since the other will have to wait for the first one to commit. Since you start both statements at the same time, it's not deterministic which of those first grabs the lock. If the delete statement picks first, it will delete node and rels, and the match of the 2nd will fail (since the node has gone)

Comment: If the delete statement run first, the 2nd match process indeed will fail, but it shouldn't return error, instead it should return empty data. I'm thinking what happened was when `SET n._fake=1` line was met on 2nd process, it halted the query execution until the 1st process released the lock. Then when it's released, it tried to resume again the query execution to the next line: `CREATE (n)-[:ACTS_IN]->(m:Movie {title: \"Hello World\"})`, however the node `n` has already been deleted by the 1st process, that's why the error is `Unable to load NODE with id ...`.

Comment: You're right. In this case you should grab a lock on another node that is not subject to change. Maybe create one specific technincal lock node: `CREATE (:Lock)` and instead set/remove the fake property on this one. Every statement requiring the lock would then start with `MATCH (l:Lock) SET l._fake=1 WITH l ...<do real work>... REMOVE l._fake`

Comment: I also ran into a problem necessitating manual locking. The popular APOC plugin for Neo4j has a selection of explicit Locking procedures that can be called via Cypher: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_locking